# What is the purpose of b <-c() in this code?

Tags: r

I have written a code to find a positive integer that has more divisors than any smaller positive integer has. My code is right but I noticed that I wrote a step only because I had solved other questions similarly but I don't really understand the intuition of why we write this particular line:

```
b <- c()
```

Also, why is there a "b" in c(b, sum..) as in the below line:

```
 b <- c(b, sum(p %% c(1:p) == 0))
```

Here is the full code:

```
code <- function(n) {
  if (n < 1 | n %% 1 != 0)
    print("Only positive integers allowed")
  else if (n <= 2) 
    return(TRUE) 
  else {
    a <- sum(n %% c(1:n) == 0) 
    b <- c()
    for (p in 1:(n-1)) {                       
      b <- c(b, sum(p %% c(1:p) == 0))
    }
    return(max(b) < a) 
  }
}

code(8)
code(6)
code(-7)
```

Comment: Seems like you're declaring an empty object as `b`, then adding to it in each iteration of the for-loop. Which, btw, is probably not an efficient way to do whatever you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in comments the purpose of `b<-c()` is to initialise an empty vector and fill it in the loop. Also the reason why you are using `b <- c(b,sum(p%%c(1:p)== 0))` is to append new values to already existing values of `b`.

For example,

```
b <- c()
b
#NULL
b <- c(b, 1)
b
#[1] 1
b <- c(b, 2)
b
#[1] 1 2
```

Usually, it is not a good practice to grow an object in a loop, it is highly inefficient to do that. If the size of output is fixed you can initialise a vector with fixed size and then fill it in the loop.

```
code <- function(n){
  if (n<1 | n%%1!=0)
    print("Only positive integers allowed")
  else if (n <= 2) 
    return(TRUE) 
  else{
    a <- sum(n%%c(1:n) == 0) 
    b <- integer(n-1) #Creates a vector with 0's of length n-1
    for (p in 1:(n-1)) {                       
      b[p] <- sum(p%%c(1:p)== 0)
    }
    return(max(b) < a) 
  }
}
```

Or in this case you can save only the max value of `b` since all other values are not important.

```
code <- function(n){
  if (n<1 | n%%1!=0)
    print("Only positive integers allowed")
  else if (n <= 2) 
    return(TRUE) 
  else{
    a <- sum(n%%c(1:n) == 0) 
    max_b <- 0
    for (p in 1:(n-1)) {                       
       val <- sum(p%%c(1:p)== 0)
       if(val > max_b) max_b <- val
    }
    return(max_b < a) 
  }
}
```

Comment: If in your function you write `print(b)` just before `return(max(b) < a)` and run `code(8)` you'll notice that it will print`1 2 2 3 2 4 2` which is of length 7 i.e 8-1. If you run `code(5)` you'll see it prints `1 2 2 3` which is length 4 i.e 5 - 1. Hence you always have output of length `n-1` in `b` that is why I have initialised `b` as `b <- integer(n-1)`. The square bracket is used to extract element from vector but it can also change the value at specific position. For example,`b <- 1:5`, `b[1]` would give you 1st value in `b` i.e 1 but you can change the 1st value of `b` `b[1] <- 10`.